# jQuery input on change when ajax send request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Have problem on input on change, when ajax send request to php file it implements information in inputs.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group" id="kalb1">
        <input type='text' id="galutinis2" name='mer[]' value="-" disabled>
        <input type='text' name='ker[]' value="-" disabled>
        <input type='text' name='ser[]' value="-" disabled>
        <input type='text' name='per[]' value="-" disabled>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('input', '#galutinis2', function() {
    var galutinis = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(galutinis);
});
```

PHP implements inputs:

```
 if(isset($_POST['per']))) {
     $produktas = $_POST['per'];
     $infos = CalSkaiciuokle::where("id", $produktas);

      foreach ($infos as $info) {
         echo "<input type='text' id='galutinis2' name='mer[]' value=" .$info->name. " disabled>";
         echo "<input type='text' name='ker[]' value=".$info->surname." disabled>";
         echo "<input type='text' name='ser[]' value=".$info->city." disabled>";
         echo "<input type='text' name='per[]' value=".$info->address." disabled>";
     }
     exit;
}
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).on('change', '.subcategory', function() {
var subcategory_id = $(this).attr('id');
//alert($("#"+subcategory_id).val());
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'ajaxLoader.php',
    data: {
        per:$("#"+subcategory_id).val()
    },
    success: function (response) {
        document.getElementById("kalb"+parseInt(subcategory_id.match(/[0-9]+/)[0], 10)).innerHTML=response;
    }
});
```

});
Where can be a problem for not alerting the value ?

Comment: `input` is not a jquery [event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/). Also you haven't included your ajax call

Comment: @Mantas, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to pick up input value that was inserted in input after ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are replacing the original form and no events related to "input value change" (`blur`, `change`, etc.) are called. You can trigger them yourself in your AJAX callback.

```
success: function(){
    document.getElementById("kalb"+par ...
    $('#galutinis2').trigger('input'); // or better use builtin events
}
```

Comment: It worked when i change trigger('input') to trigger('change'); Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your jQuery code in a `document.ready`? Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('blur', '#galutinis2', function() {
        var galutinis = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(galutinis);
    });
}); //END document.ready
```

Also, note that you must leave the input field for a `blur()` event to fire.

If you wish to catch individual keystroke activity, try `.keyup()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', '#galutinis2', function() {
        var galutinis = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(galutinis);
    });
}); //END document.ready
```

Comment: yes I'm wrapped my code with document.ready. This code didn't catch new inserted value too. And I'm not inserting with key, I'm inserting values from database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<script>
    var subcategory_id;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change', '.subcategory', function() {
            subcategory_id = this.id;
            //alert($("#"+subcategory_id).val()); <-- does this work??
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'ajaxLoader.php',
                data: {
                    per:$("#"+subcategory_id).val()
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var num = parseInt(subcategory_id.match(/[0-9]+/)[0], 10);
                    alert('Num: '+num);
                    $('#kalb'+num).val(response);
                }
            });
        });

    }); //END document.ready
</script>
```

Note that the var `subcategory_id` is not available in your AJAX `success` function, so must be declared globally (outside the functions in which it is being used)

---

Also, you may wish to test what you are receiving in the `ajaxLoader.php` file, by just echoing back the POST data:

```
<?php
    die( $_POST['per'] );
```

And modify `success` function:

```
success: function (response) {
alert(response);
```

Comment: ajax function working good, it return all information in my input field. Maybe the problem is that I append my old html tag with new from ajaxLoader (PHP code on my question) and jquery don't catch that?

Comment: Did you do the test I suggest at bottom of my answer (new content)? Does the ajax success function alert the correct data here: `alert(response)` ?

Comment: Does this `alert('Num: '+num);` *(note its location in the ax success fn)* alert the correct number for this control `$('#kalb'+num)`.  Also, add this alert below the other: `alert( $('#kalb'+num).length ); `

Comment: Yes, but that are your trying to do?

Comment: Note updated comment above (refresh page). Trying to establish that the `$('#kalb'+num)` element exists, and is being correctly populated by `response` variable

Comment: the code alert('Num: '+num); $('#kalb'+num).val(response); returning good values. But  alert( $('#kalb'+num).length ); always return 1